# Lightning Process Builder vs. an Apex trigger

Tags: apex, process-builder

What is the diff between Lightning Process Builder vs. an Apex trigger? and knows when to use?

Comment: I would recommend going thru this trail to understand the different process tools and when to use which one.. https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/business_process_automation/process_whichtool

Comment: An apex trigger is less buggy and less quirky at this point. That aside, process builder requires no code (for the most part) and can do much more than WFR (Create Records, update related records, etc). Sticking with the principles of clicks not code, I would try process builder over triggers if possible. Its bugginess will get better and it works for a lot of things now so go through the trailhead and give it a shot.